# Can't run python cmd command. Throws syntax error

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I am using `node-gyp configure` because a frontend project needs this. I am using Windows 10 and the whole process breaks apart.

This is the error message:

```
$ node-gyp rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.20.1 | win32 | x64
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\xetra11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
```

I tried to reproduce that python problem:

```
$ python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
  File "<string>", line 1
    import
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Unable to initialize device PRN
```

**Python version is 3.7.1**

Any idea how to get around this? Do I need to downgrade my python version or what?

Comment: This `print` syntax works only with Python 2.x

Comment: Add parentheses to your print: `print("%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3])`

Comment: Your attempt at reproducing the problem failed because the argument to `python -c` has to be a single, quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

print needs ("text", or_variable) in 3.x of python versions.